# How to use System.DirectoryServices with DNX Core 5.0?

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I'm trying to integrated Active Directory with my ASP.Net 5.0 application, but it seems that System.DirectoryServices is not part of the DNX Core 5.0.

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": {
    "frameworkAssemblies": {
      "System.DirectoryServices": "4.0.0.0"
    }
  },
  "dnxcore50": {}
}
```

Is there any way how I can add it to the Core 5.0, or maybe ther is other library now which I should use for Active Directory?

Comment: Active Directory is not cross platform, so it won't be part of dnxcore50. You will have to switch to LDAP.

Comment: Thanks, could you please provide more info, or link for more readings?

Comment: Mono's LDAP comes from Novell, https://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/appnote/1673.html, you might try if that code can be reused for .NET Core.